# How to Consume the Latest Event with Azure Event Hubs Go SDK (azeventhubs)?

Tags: azure, go, azure-iot-hub

I'm in the process of migrating from **azure-event-hubs-go/v3** to the newer **azeventhubs** Go SDK. In the older SDK, there was a **ReceiveOption** argument that allowed me to specify from where to start consuming events.

In the new SDK, I'm using the following code to initialize the processor:

```
processor, err := azeventhubs.NewProcessor(
    e.ConsumerClient, 
    checkpointStore, 
    &azeventhubs.ProcessorOptions{
        UpdateInterval: time.Second, 
        Prefetch: 0, 
        StartPositions: azeventhubs.StartPositions{
            Default: azeventhubs.StartPosition{
                Latest: to.Ptr(true), 
                EnqueuedTime: to.Ptr(time.Now()), 
                Inclusive: true
            }
        }
    }
)
```

However, I've noticed that the events are being consumed from the last checkpoint rather than from the most recently sent events.

**What I've Tried:**
I've experimented with both **ConsumingEventsUsingConsumerClient** and **ConsumingEventsWithCheckpoints** examples, but they both behave the same way, consuming events from the last checkpoint rather than the most recent events.

**What I'm Expecting:**
I want the processor to start consuming the latest events sent from the device, which sends a message every second. How can I achieve this behavior using azeventhubs Go SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially struggled to grasp the underlying mechanisms of AMQP. However, I am pleased to report that the issue has been successfully resolved.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)

for _, partition := range p.PartitionIDs {
    go func(partition string) {
        defer wg.Done()

        partitionClient, err := consumerClient.NewPartitionClient(partition, nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        receiveCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), time.Second*30)
        defer cancel()

        for {
            events, err := partitionClient.ReceiveEvents(receiveCtx, 1, nil)

            if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded) {
                panic(err)
            }

            for _, evt := range events {
                fmt.Printf("partition: %s\n", partition)
                fmt.Printf("Body: %s\n", string(evt.Body))
            }
        }
    }(partition)
}

wg.Wait()
```

I extend my gratitude to the Azure customer support services team for their invaluable assistance.